# How do I replace the numbers in a textfile with larger numbers?

Tags: php, replace

I'd to increment all the numbers that appear in a text file. The file contains an index of page numbers, but all of the page numbers need to be incremented by 'x' number of pages, to take into account additional introductory pages that were introduced before the index was written.

Eg.

philosophy

of mind 44-45

of physics 202, 213, 219

philosophical arguments

inductive 33

deductive 89, 102

Thanks!

Comment: What is your code at the moment?

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part, and we're always glad to help :-)

Comment: Come on guys. It's one line of code. It's not like they're asking someone to write an entire program for them.

Comment: @Don'tPanic do one up then ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This should be a fairly simple task with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)/', function($nums) { return $nums[0] + 1; }, $str);
```

The regular expression matches the numbers, and the callback returns the incremented version of each number to the replacement function.

You can also pass a variable with the increment value into the callback with `use` rather than hard-coding it there.

```
$increment = 5;    
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)/', function($nums) use ($increment) {
    return $nums[0] + $increment;
}, $str);
```

<sub>Note that this assumes you already know how to read the file contents in and write it back out, and you just didn't know how to do the replacing.</sub>

Comment: I quote: *"Come on guys. It's one line of code."* - That's more than one line *lo!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's one line-ish :)

Comment: Ok... *'ish* it is then :-))